# How to parse tables without id on HTML using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have a problem getting the values of a table in HTML cause it doesn't have a `id`s. I need to get all the values on the second column and keep them into an array. I am using HtmlAgilityPack and my problems comes when selecting nodes:

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument
Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
Dim str As String

doc = Web.Load("http://www.dietas.net/tablas-y-calculadoras/tabla-de-composicion-nutricional-de-los-alimentos/carnes-y-derivados/aves/pechuga-de-pollo.html#")

Dim nodes_filas As HtmlNode() = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='']//tr").ToArray
Dim nodes_columnas As HtmlNode() = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td").ToArray

For Each row As HtmlNode In nodes_filas
    For Each column As HtmlNode In nodes_columnas
        str = column.InnerHtml & vbCrLf
    Next
Next
```

This is the table:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:13px;color:#55711C;padding-bottom:5px;">Aporte por raci&oacute;n</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td width="125">Energ&iacute;a [Kcal]</td>
    <td class="td_right">145,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prote&iacute;na [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">22,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td>Hidratos carbono [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">0,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fibra [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">0,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td>Grasa total [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">6,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AGS [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">1,91</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td>AGM [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">1,92</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AGP [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">1,52</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td>AGP /AGS</td>
    <td class="td_right">0,79</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>(AGP + AGM) / AGS</td>
    <td class="td_right"> 1,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td>Colesterol [mg]</td>
    <td class="td_right">62,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alcohol [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">0,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
    <td>Agua [g]</td>
    <td class="td_right">71,60</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have VB installed but C# version should be enough to give you an idea. You have `td_right` class, you can use either lambda or xpath to query it.
I like lambda/linq version more because I am familiar with linq, and I don't need to remember XPATH syntax.

Lambda:

```
    public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
    {
        var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
        var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
        return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
    }

var url = "http://www.dietas.net/tablas-y-calculadoras/tabla-de-composicion-nutricional-de-los-alimentos/carnes-y-derivados/aves/pechuga-de-pollo.html#";
        var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDoc = htmlWeb.Load(url);
        var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").Where(_ => _.HasClass("td_right")).Select(_ => _.InnerText);
```

XPATH:

```
var nodes2 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='td_right']");
```

Comment: Perfect solution!! Thank you so much!